# How can I remove data type information from my xml in MarkLogic Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I have an XML data generated via Javascript in MarkLogic:

```html
<Activities datatype="array">
 <Activity>
   <ActivityCrewSize>10</ActivityCrewSize>
   <ActivitySeqNo>1</ActivitySeqNo>
   <ActivityDesc/>
 </Activity>
</Activities>
```

How can I remove the datatype information so it will just look like this:

```html
<Activities>
 <Activity>
   <ActivityCrewSize>10</ActivityCrewSize>
   <ActivitySeqNo>1</ActivitySeqNo>
   <ActivityDesc/>
 </Activity>
 </Activities>
```

```js
obj.Activities = [];

let act = {
    '$type': 'Activity',
    '$version': '0.0.1',
     } 
  
for (const item of activities) {

 act.ActivityCrewSize = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "CrewSize", true)); 
 act.ActivitySeqNo = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "SeqNo", true)); 
 act.ActivityDesc = hl.elementText(item, null, true);

 obj.Activities.push(act); 
}

return obj;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remove the data type information by converting the data using the `Sequence.from` function in MarkLogic. Hope this may help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can **Remove an attribute by name**.

```js
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Activities")[0].removeAttribute('datatype');
```

```html
<Activities datatype="array">
 <Activity>
   <ActivityCrewSize>10</ActivityCrewSize>
   <ActivitySeqNo>1</ActivitySeqNo>
   <ActivityDesc/>
 </Activity>
</Activities>
```

Comment: If your XML is a string, parse it into a DOM object first: `var parser = new DOMParser();`
`var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(yourXMLstring,"text/xml");` See https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Comment: Thanks for the response guys but the functions suggested is not available in MarkLogic javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you need it short and simple, this may satisfy your requirements.

```
var _xml = '<Activities datatype="array"><Activity><ActivityCrewSize>10</ActivityCrewSize<ActivitySeqNo>1</ActivitySeqNo><ActivityDesc/></Activity></Activities>';

var _test = _xml.replace(/\sdatatype\=\".+\"/g,'');
alert(_test);
```

This will wildcard-remove ANY occurance of ' datatype="(anything)"' from your XML-String.
https://jsfiddle.net/53817ofj/

If you need it a bit more complex, you may want to take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but what I'm looking for is specifically a solution for MarkLogic Javascript